# Cannot use insertAdjacentElement properly

Tags: javascript

I wanted to have the message "This input field cannot be blank" appearing after each input text and email field. However, I failed to do so. Only one message was appeared after the last input field (i.e. Card Number) 
Would you please help me spot out what happened? I tried for 1 hour. 
Thank you very much.

```
//javascript file 
const elementAction = {

    createMessage: function(insertedElement, value, elementCollection, position ){
       const newElement= document.createElement(insertedElement);
       newElement.innerHTML= value;
       elementAction.insertAlert(position, elementCollection, newElement);
       },

    insertAlert: function(position, elementCollection, insertedElement){
       for(let i=0; i<elementCollection.length; i++){
       elementCollection[i].insertAdjacentElement(position, insertedElement);
       }
    },
    get: function(element){
        const elementCollection = document.querySelectorAll(element);
        return elementCollection;
     }
 };

 const inputFieldCollection = elementAction.get("[type='email'], [type='text']");
 elementAction.createMessage('p', 'This input field cannot be blank', inputFieldCollection, 'afterend');
```

```
//HTML file 
<label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
    <label for="mail">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email">
    <label for="cc-num">Card Number:</label>
    <input id="cc-num" name="user_cc-num" type="text">
```

Comment: you need to create `newElement` for each element in `elementCollection` - because you've only created a single "new element", and  `insertAdjacentElement` will MOVE an existing element to the new spot - combine `createMessage` and `insertAlert` into one function, and put the `document.createElement` code inside the for loop

Comment: Oh, I successfully did it after following your instruction. Thank you very much. But I don't fully understand the rationale behind. Do you mean const newElement= document.createElement(insertedElement) is not a copy and thus it cannot be re-used? Perhaps I got confused about element object.

Comment: Perhaps I mixed this with the library JQuery...

Comment: newElement is an element ... a single element ... it can't exist in multiple places ...

Comment: @JaromandaX I see. Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it.